# Create a script with Multiple languages

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

**Problem:** I would like to be able to create a aspx file that contains multiple paragraphs that are in different languages.

Example:

English: Here is an example. Call ###-###-####

Spanish: Aquí hay un ejemplo. Llama a ###-###-####

Japanese: 日本語を話される場合、無料 ###-###-####
etc.

I have tried to do it in html but when I try to generate it, Japanese and other languages characters would not render correctly. Is their a way to achieve this.

I did the following:

```
<%
string value1 = "日本語を話される場合";
string value2 = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(value1);
Response.Write(value2);
%>
```

and the following results was generated:

æ—¥æœ¬èªžã‚’è©±ã•ã‚Œã‚‹å ´åˆ

I also tried the following:

```
    <style>
body                {font-family: "Times New Roman",serif; }
*[lang="ar"]        {font-family: "Scheherazade",serif; 
                     font-size: 120%;}
*[lang="zh-Hant"]   {font-family: Kai,KaiTi,serif;}
*[lang="zh-Hans"]   {font-family: DFKai-SB,BiauKai, serif;}
*[lang="din"]       {font-family: "Doulos SIL",serif;}

.ar     {font-family: "Scheherazade",serif; 
         font-size: 120%;}
.zht    {font-family: PMingLiU, MingLiU,serif;}
.zhs    {font-family: SimSum-18030, SimHei,serif;}
.din    {font-family: "Doulos SIL",serif;}
</style>


<p>It is polite to welcome people in their own language:</p>
<ul>
    <li class="zhs" lang="zh-Hans">欢迎</li>
    <li class="zht" lang="zh-Hant">歡迎</li>
    <li class="el" lang="el">Καλοσωρίσατε</li>
    <li class="ar" lang="ar">اهلا وسهلا</li>
    <li class="ru" lang="ru">Добро пожаловать</li>
    <li class="din" lang="din">Kudual</li>
</ul>
```

and I get the following results:

æ¬¢è¿Ž

æ­¡è¿Ž

ÎšÎ±Î»Î¿ÏƒÏ‰ÏÎ¯ÏƒÎ±Ï„Îµ

Ø§Ù‡Ù„Ø§ ÙˆØ³Ù‡Ù„Ø§

Ð”Ð¾Ð±Ñ€Ð¾ Ð¿Ð¾Ð¶Ð°Ð»Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ‚ÑŒ

Kudual

Comment: have you tried `HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode`?

Comment: @DimosK I have tried to do it but it didnt work. Please look what I did above

Comment: Are you providing the correct fonts within the html/css? Even if you are providing the correct font-name that the display language should use, you may also need to provide the font itself, hosted somewhere. Be careful though, some fonts have copyrights and may not be distributable.

Comment: @gmiley: I am new to this and never tried this before. How would I provide the correct fonts? Would I do a span within the Response.Write to describe the font and font size?? Again a noob at this

Comment: Try starting here: https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-lang

Comment: @gmiley:  So I would not need to use the approach that Dimos K suggested and I have tried that very same link and the approach did not work

Comment: @gmiley: I tried the following: <style>
<em:lang(ja){font-style: normal; text-emphasis: dot; text-emphasis-position: over right;}>
</style>

<p> This is <em>English</em>, but <span lang="ja">される</span></p> and it displayed the following: ã•ã‚Œã‚‹

Comment: That page is just a starting point for a place to look, I don't think there is any specific implementation for what you want. What you tried is just for specifying how a language should be emphasized, not the font. You will need to specify font information, and possibly font file location.

Comment: @gmiley: I understand that and I went through that. That is why I was asking if you can elaborate on font information and font file location

Comment: Does it work in a plain .html file? If so, the issue is likely with your character encoding of the .aspx file or ASP.net itself.

Comment: @ConnorGurney: No, it does not. It renders the same characters as shown as above

Comment: @Everyone: Is their a link or a reference that I can be directed to better assist for what I am looking for

Comment: @Robert: It looks like the issue is your character encoding. What program are you saving the file in?

Comment: @ConnorGurney:  saving as a asp file.

Comment: @Robert: What program are you using? Visual Studio?

Comment: @ConnorGurney: Yes

Comment: @ConnorGurney: Thanks